# Cordova CLI build Android fails with exception Unsupported major.minor version

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to build an Android app using Cordova CLI as

```
cordova build android
```

However, the build fails with the following exception

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :         Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main"
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
 Exception in thread "main"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How can I fix this issue? I am using Java Version 1.7 and Android Studio v2.2.3 and have android-23 in sdk folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in Java and android version. Please reduce your Java version.
From Java 8 to minor version.

Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting Android 5.0 and higher.
This is from android official page.

> Before you set up Android Studio, be sure you have installed JDK 6 or
>   higher (the JRE alone is not sufficient)—JDK 7 is required when
>   developing for Android 5.0 and higher. To check if you have JDK
>   installed (and which version), open a terminal and type javac
>   -version. If the JDK is not available or the version is lower than 6, go download JDK.

Comment: When I tried with Java 7 earlier it still gave the same issue. When I run `cordova build android` the first few lines are `ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_79 `

Comment: try to use android sdk 23 with jdk 7. issue with jre version your jdk and jre version should be same

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a class compiled using Java 1.8 compiler into a lower JRE version e.g. JRE 1.7 or JRE 1.6.
Your output shows that youre not using Java 1.8

```
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Process 'comman`enter code here`d 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' <--------
```

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out, I had put in the log when trying with Java 7. Have updated question.

Comment: Are you using any libraries which might not be compilant with java 1.8?

Comment: I have just created a basic cordova project and added plugins for inAppBrowser and GeoLocation. Then when I build the app I get this error.

Comment: Strange, it really looks like youre environment isnt configured right.
What does your $JAVA_HOME say ?

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`